# Need to set rich:simpleTogglePanel open=false after clicked command button

Tags: javascript, richfaces

Need to set  rich:simpleTogglePanel open=false after clicked command button 
below is my command button coding ,what should i do to change my simpleTogglePanel open=false after clicked this command button

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Search" status="waitSearchStatusSO" 
                    id="soSearchBtn"
                    reRender="soSearchResultsPanel,soErroMessages,searchSoKey"
                    action="#{soSearchAction.processAction}"
                    onmouseover="this.style.color='#d30100'"
                    onmouseout="this.style.color='#ffffff'"
                    onclick="javascript:validateSOsearch();"
                    oncomplete="javascript:Richfaces.hideModalPanel('processpanel');"
                    styleClass="btnBackground"
                    disabled="#{ viewScope.soform.waveSoExistFlag == 'false' ?false: !viewScope.soform.searchAccess}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (SimpleTogglePanelManager.panels.get(panel.id).status == "true") {
    SimpleTogglePanelManager.toggleOnClient(event, panel.id);
  }
```

For more details refer here:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/183160

Comment: @Dhana You are welcome. If the answer was helpful to you, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)